# How can I get a collection for a DTO member with nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, dto

I need to get a collection property populated in a DTO and I'm having trouble finding any information on doing this.

I tried to do it like this:

```
ICriteria selectCriteria = Session.CreateCriteria<DataRun>()
            .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                .Add(Projections.Property("SomeCollection"), "Collection"))
            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<MyDto>());
```

but MyDto.Collection is always null.  Am I doing this wrong, is this even possible?

Also, I had originally planned on doing this with a SubQuery so I could just fill my DTO's collection with other DTOs but this will not work because the result of the subquery has more than 1 row (as it should) and Sqlit does not like that (throws an exception).  what is the right thing to do here?

Comment: I think you're trying to do a one-to-many which should be done in your mapping but I'm not really sure. Can you post your mapping files?

Comment: I am doing a one-to-many and my mapped entities work fine for this sort of thing but I don't want to get my mapped entity back, I want a DTO with a bunch of properties and what not that are specific to the view they will be used on.

Answer (score 0):

I've retrieved collection properties in my project with the following syntax:

```
public IList<ChildCollectionType> GetChildObjectsByParentId(Int32 id)
{
    ISession session = GetSession();//Get NHibernate session routine
    return session.Load<ParentDTO>(id).ChildCollectionProperty;
}
```

where **id** is the key of the parent object.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your original question correctly.  I didn't realise that you were trying to populate a custom DTO with a collection property.  There are a few other posts on here with people having issues with aliasToBean e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504054/simple-hibernate-aliastobean-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You may use custom transformation.

```
ICriteria selectCriteria = Session.CreateCriteria<DataRun>()
            .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                .Add(Projections.Property("SomeCollection"), "Collection"))
            .TransformUsing(new CustomTransformer());
```

Here is your custom transformer implementation

```
public class CustomTransformer : IResultTransformer
    {
        public System.Collections.IList TransformList(System.Collections.IList collection)
        {
            return collection;
        }

        public object TransformTuple(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
        {
            return new MyDto
            {
                //map your data to dto and convert to data type if needed
                YourProperty1 = tuple[0],
                YourProperty12 = (int)tuple[1]
            };
        }
    }
```