# Simple Hibernate aliasToBean() not working

Tags: hibernate

The following code isn't working for me:

```
List results = getSession().createCriteria(User.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("userName"))
    )
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UserSummary.class))
    .list();
```

Funny enough though if I remove the `setResultTransformer()` I get a list of userNames returned back perfectly fine.

Here is my UserSummary class:

```
public class UserSummary {

    private String userName;
    private String clickUrl;
    private Integer id;

    public UserSummary() {}

    public UserSummary(Integer id, String userName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.clickUrl = clickUrl;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getClickUrl() {
        return clickUrl;
    }

    public void setClickUrl(String clickUrl) {
        this.clickUrl = clickUrl;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed it.

Had to change my projection so it looked like this..

```
.add(Projections.property("userName"), "userName")
```

Odd.. but whatever works I guess.

Answer (score 5):

```java
.add(Projections.property("userName"), "userName");
```

..is *correct* in this situation.

The `aliasToBean()` method creates a *ResultTransformer* that will inject aliased values into instances of the UserSummary class via property methods or fields. The second parameter of the `add()` method is where the projected *property alias* is specified. Here you have specified 'userName' which is the property in the UserSummary class the projected property will be mapped to. That's why it didn't work in the first instance. The Hibernate lib did not know what UserSummary field/setter to map the property to. Take out the `aliasToBean()` method and it isn't going to attempt to do any mapping. So, if one had:

```java
private String userFullName;

public UserSummary(Integer id, String userFullName) {
   this.id = id;
   this.userFullName = userFullName;
   this.clickUrl = clickUrl;
}

public String getUserFullName() {
   return userFullName;
}
```

The `add()` method would be as follows:

```java
.add(Projections.property("userName"), "userFullName");
```

As long as both *userName* of the User class and *userFullName* of UserSummary class are using the same ***type*** you're good to go.